# onetomany lazy fetching hibernate essue

Tags: java, hibernate

Hy, i have lazy fetching problem and don't undestant why it happens.
I have two entites:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSONS")
public class Persons {

    ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public List<Cards> cards = new ArrayList<Cards>();

    ...
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CARDS")
public class Cards {

    ...

    @ManyToOne (fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PERSON_ID")
    @JsonBackReference
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private Persons person;

    ...
}
```

And person's repository:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class PersonRepository {
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    public List<Persons> getAll() {
        return getSession().createCriteria(Persons.class).list();
    }
    protected Session getSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }
}
```

When I try get persons, I also get all cards collection for every person, but i don't want to get this collection. How I can resovle this problem?

Sql query:

```
    select
        this_.PERSON_ID as PERSON_ID1_10_2_,
        this_.CITY_ID as CITY_ID8_10_2_,
        this_.EMAIL as EMAIL2_10_2_,
        this_.FIRST_NAME as FIRST_NAME3_10_2_,
        this_.LAST_NAME as LAST_NAME4_10_2_,
        this_.MOBILE_NUMBER as MOBILE_NUMBER5_10_2_,
        this_.NICKNAME as NICKNAME6_10_2_,
        this_.PASSWORD as PASSWORD7_10_2_,
        this_.ROLE_ID as ROLE_ID9_10_2_,
        cities2_.CITY_ID as CITY_ID1_5_0_,
        cities2_.CITY_NAME as CITY_NAME2_5_0_,
        rollers3_.ROLE_ID as ROLE_ID1_11_1_,
        rollers3_.ROLE_TYPE as ROLE_TYPE2_11_1_ 
    from
        PERSONS this_ 
    inner join
        CITIES cities2_ 
            on this_.CITY_ID=cities2_.CITY_ID 
    left outer join
        ROLLERS rollers3_ 
            on this_.ROLE_ID=rollers3_.ROLE_ID
Hibernate: 
    select
        this_.PERSON_ID as PERSON_ID1_10_2_,
        this_.CITY_ID as CITY_ID8_10_2_,
        this_.EMAIL as EMAIL2_10_2_,
        this_.FIRST_NAME as FIRST_NAME3_10_2_,
        this_.LAST_NAME as LAST_NAME4_10_2_,
        this_.MOBILE_NUMBER as MOBILE_NUMBER5_10_2_,
        this_.NICKNAME as NICKNAME6_10_2_,
        this_.PASSWORD as PASSWORD7_10_2_,
        this_.ROLE_ID as ROLE_ID9_10_2_,
        cities2_.CITY_ID as CITY_ID1_5_0_,
        cities2_.CITY_NAME as CITY_NAME2_5_0_,
        rollers3_.ROLE_ID as ROLE_ID1_11_1_,
        rollers3_.ROLE_TYPE as ROLE_TYPE2_11_1_ 
    from
        PERSONS this_ 
    inner join
        CITIES cities2_ 
            on this_.CITY_ID=cities2_.CITY_ID 
    left outer join
        ROLLERS rollers3_ 
            on this_.ROLE_ID=rollers3_.ROLE_ID
Result set row: 0
```

`
I did mistacke with sql query.

I configure logger in appcontroller class:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/home"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String homePage(ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("greeting", "Welcome to the first page of the project");
    List<Persons> personsList = personService.getUsers();
    if (Const.DEBUG) {
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            for (Persons persons : personsList) {
                logger.debug("Array Card size " + persons.getCards().size() + " for " + persons.getNickname());
                for (Cards card : persons.getCards()) {
                    logger.debug("CardName " + card.getCardName());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return "welcome";
}
```

And then run project in debug mode I get this in console output file:

```
[DEBUG] 2017-05-02 08:32:46 com.team.mvc.controller.AppController:homePage:55 - Array Card size 0 for Alex
[DEBUG] 2017-05-02 08:32:49 com.team.mvc.controller.AppController:homePage:55 - Array Card size 0 for ui1
[DEBUG] 2017-05-02 08:32:50 com.team.mvc.controller.AppController:homePage:55 - Array Card size 0 for ui2
[DEBUG] 2017-05-02 08:32:50 com.team.mvc.controller.AppController:homePage:55 - Array Card size 1 for vvv
[DEBUG] 2017-05-02 08:32:51 com.team.mvc.controller.AppController:homePage:57 - CardName null
[DEBUG] 2017-05-02 08:32:53 com.team.mvc.controller.AppController:homePage:55 - Array Card size 1 for Sam
[DEBUG] 2017-05-02 08:32:54 com.team.mvc.controller.AppController:homePage:55 - Array Card size 0 for Alex
[DEBUG] 2017-05-02 08:32:54 com.team.mvc.controller.AppController:homePage:57 - CardName null
[DEBUG] 2017-05-02 08:32:55 com.team.mvc.controller.AppController:homePage:55 - Array Card size 0 for Alex
[DEBUG] 2017-05-02 08:32:56 com.team.mvc.controller.AppController:homePage:55 - Array Card size 0 for ui1
[DEBUG] 2017-05-02 08:32:56 com.team.mvc.controller.AppController:homePage:55 - Array Card size 0 for ui1
[DEBUG] 2017-05-02 08:32:56 com.team.mvc.controller.AppController:homePage:55 - Array Card size 0 for 7
[DEBUG] 2017-05-02 08:32:56 com.team.mvc.controller.AppController:homePage:55 - Array Card size 0 for ui2
```

it means that user "vvv" have one card and lazy fetch don't work.

Class PersonService:

```
    @Service
    @Transactional
    public class PersonService {

        ...

        @Autowired
        PersonRepository personRepository;

        public List<Persons> getUsers() {
            List<Persons> personList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Persons person : personRepository.getAll()) {
                if (person.getRole().getRoleType().equals("USER"))
                    personList.add(person);
            }
            return personList;
        }

        ...
    }
```

Where I did mistake?

Comment: What sql query is printed by hibernate in console?

Comment: just to be clear, when getAll() exits, the Cards are already fetched?

Comment: add sql query. Yes, cards was fetched

Comment: what's may be wrong. I think that annotation  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY) don't work?

Comment: Sql query doesn't join `cards` table, but it joins `cities` and `rollers` tables. So `fetch = FetchType.LAZY` on `List<Cards> cards` works.

Comment: I'm sorry. I wrong

Comment: Add more information

Comment: @JaySmith,  You were right